# Real - time adjustment of route based on Traffic condition

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

With the similarities of WAZE App.

I wonder what API i can possibly use to make an mobile application that will dynamically / automatically adjust its route based on traffic level / condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google maps in android you need to call setTrafficEnabled(true) on your googleMaps object.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic

If you want the raw data it's a little more complicated and almost impractical.

You can get the layer from google maps and parse the server response(but it's really hard). 
 You could use Google Enterprise (NOT FREE) https://enterprise.google.com/maps/products/mapsapi.html and it will calculate routes with including traffic data.

Or if you want just incidents use bingMaps API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441726.aspx

There might be some other solutions, but they are not free, it's a complex service and people work hard for that information, they will charge for it.

Comment: Last question. Would it be possible to use multiple different API from different services?

Comment: Like , Using Traffic API from MAPQUEST while Using Google Map API. then apply Skobbler Direction API. I'm sorry for these question. I'm still researching if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to put this data over google maps you would have to  draw over the map using the information you gathered. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools  . Another option would be to build a custom layer on top of the google maps.